# Dump data from one database table to the other database

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

I have to write a code in vb.net (2010).
To get a data from Database A table 1 and dump it to Database B Table 2.
What’s the best way to do this? Most efficient way? I know I can do this very easily in sql management studio but I need to write a code to do this in vb.net.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For MSSQL (which I believe you use if you use .NET) the best and fastest way is to use bulk inserts.

You can find the documentation here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188365.aspx

Comment: Yes it is sql server. But I need to write code in Vb.net (2010)

Comment: The code that you should write should dump a text file with the data in a specified (in that link) format. After that by calling the bulk insert sql statement the server will import that file.

Comment: am sorry but one is sql database and other one I had to use ODBC not a sql database.

Comment: Then you have 2 ways of doing this: one is to select everything from one DB and just insert into the other, which might prove (this can be done in chunks or all) and the other way is to build a script to dump on the second DB and after it is completed to execute it.

Comment: I prefer the second one as it allows inserting in one transaction.

Comment: I did not get clear about second option. Can you please give me an example. Thanks

Comment: You can use as an example the phpMyAdmin generated MySQL script for a DB. It will generate a text file that will contain all the table creates that you need, after that inserts, indexes and so on. I think from what you wrote that you only need data, so your text file should look something like a list of INSERT INTO xxx (..) VALUES (..)

Comment: I got it, I have used PhpmYadmin a lot. DoYou thinks this is the fastes option for me to import data? SHould I go with it? - Thanks!

Comment: In terms of developing time is very fast as it is just building a text file and executing it. In terms of performance, it depends on allot of things, like where is the second server. It is only one call so it should be faster then inserting row by row on a remote server. On the same machine the two options should be similar. But I personally prefer this approach as is cleaner and as I told you it can be transaction-able which is a very important aspect of importing data.

Comment: WIth your first approach of selecting from  one db and isert into other How can I do this in Sql Management studio? I think I have to link to other server for doing this? I have not done anything like this in the past. Or if I have to do ti thru VB code How would I do this? Basicaaly I will be writitng sql syntacx Select Into and then calling it as a command object?

Comment: TO be able to do this in SQL Management you have to link the Server first. This can be achieved (SQL 2008) in server objects in your SQL Server. After you link your server (in the case you have a provider for the DB you want to link) you can just use SQL commands against the DBS, using also the server name. (This is only theory as I learned about it but didn;t actually got to do it)

Answer (score 1):

You could begin by writing a SQL query to do it in Management Studio, and then get that to run from VB.Net

Your SQL will look something like:

```
SELECT * INTO DatabaseB.dbo.Table2 FROM DatabaseA.dbo.Table1
```

To run this in VB.Net, you should look at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection and System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand. You first make the SqlConnection with your database details, then you make the SqlCommand, passing in the SqlConnection and the SQL you want to run.

Don't forget to dispose the SqlConnection when you are done (preferably put it in a using block).

Comment: I am sorry but one is sql database and other one I had to use ODBC not a sql database.

Comment: You can set up Sql Server to have the other database server as a 'linked server'. If you can do that then you can easily modify the above SQL statement to work.

Comment: Really Can I use Select into to get data from different server and different database type? and then dump into sql database?

Comment: SELECT * INTO DatabaseB.dbo.Table2 FROM DatabaseA.dbo.Table1 in this  DatabaseB is non sql database Should I just use SERVERNAME.DatabaseB.dbo.Table2  in management studio?